# Is it correct to say that the statement $x\in \emptyset$ is false?

Tags: logic, terminology, definition

Usually, whether a statement $P(x)$ about a free variable $x$ is true or false depends on the value or meaning of $x.$

For example, if $P(x)$ means $x\in \{ 1, -9, 15 \},$ we can neither say that $P(x)$ is true nor that it is false if we don't know what $x$ is.

But can we say that the statement $$x\in\emptyset$$ is false? After all, it does not have any quantifier.

On the other hand, these five examples all have quantifiers (either $\forall x$ or $\exists x$), and

1. $\forall x(x\in \emptyset \Rightarrow P(x))$
   is vacuously true.
2. $\forall x(x \in U \Rightarrow x \in \emptyset)$
   is false.
3. $\exists x(x \in U \land x\in \emptyset)$
   is false.
4. $\exists x(x \in \emptyset)$
   is false.
5. $\forall x(x \in \emptyset)$
   is false.

Comment: I think every time $x\in \emptyset$ has a meaning, it is false. But a logician's answer is needed.

Comment: Yes we can. Usually we read formulas with free variables as implicitly universally quantified.

Comment: But in this case, also every assignment of a value to the free variable x will produce a false sentence.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I think what Stats Cruncher is asking is whether we can regard $x\in\emptyset$ as a false statement, even when $x$ is not considered to be universally quantified, either implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: @Joe - answered in my second comment above. But we may compare it with e.g. $x=0$.

Comment: @Joe Indeed, What Joe says is what I intended to ask about or what this question was intended for. Appreciate it, Joe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual, we are not admitting an empty domain of discourse. Then

$$x\in \emptyset$$ is an [unsatisfiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4512153/21813) open formula:

- *open formula*

  it is technically not a statement (closed formula), as it has a free variable;
- *unsatisfiable*

  it has a definite truth value False regardless of interpretation.

Comment: Why are there so many terminologies? Wow, how come people on this site are so knowledgeable?

Comment: Sorry, is there any part that you require clarification of? Honestly, outside of formal logic, nobody will bat an eyelid if I  call $x\in\emptyset$ a statement. P.S. Remember to take a look at the Answer that I linked to.

Comment: Just pay people who provide answers compliments!

Comment: Thanks, @StatsCruncher! -)

Comment: The reason there are so many terminologies is so that questions like yours can be answered clearly!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct to say that the statement  x∈∅  is false?

Yes. We usually define $\emptyset$ as follows: $~~\forall a:a\notin \emptyset$.

Postulating $x\in \emptyset$ leads to the obvious contradiction, so $x\in \emptyset$ must be false.